# Adding a Recaptcha form to my Django login page

Tags: python, django, recaptcha

I'd like to add Recaptcha to my login form. I'm following [this](https://github.com/praekelt/django-recaptcha#fields) repository but i'm having some problems: i added this to my `views.py`:

```
from django import forms
from captcha.fields import ReCaptchaField

class FormWithCaptcha(forms.Form):
    captcha = ReCaptchaField()
```

But i don't really know where to go from here. I suppose i need to add something to my `login.html` page but i don't know what. Can anyone give me some help? Note that i already added my public and private keys to my `settings.py` file.

This is the whole `views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Tutorial
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth import login, logout, authenticate
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import NewUserForm

from django import forms
from captcha.fields import ReCaptchaField

class FormWithCaptcha(forms.Form):
    captcha = ReCaptchaField()

def homepage(request):
    return render(request=request,
                  template_name="main/home.html",
                  context={"tutorials": Tutorial.objects.all})

def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = NewUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f"New Account Created: {username}")
            login(request, user)
            messages.info(request, f"You are now logged in as {username}")
            return redirect("main:homepage")
        else:
            for msg in form.error_messages:
                messages.error(request, f"{msg}: {form.error_messages[msg]}")


    form = NewUserForm
    return render(request,
                  "main/register.html",
                  context={"form":form})

def logout_request(request):
    logout(request)
    messages.info(request, "Logged out successfully!")
    return redirect("main:homepage")

def login_request(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AuthenticationForm(request, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                messages.info(request, f"You are now logged in as {username}")
                return redirect("main:homepage")
            else:
                messages.error(request, "Invalid username or password")

        else:
            messages.error(request, "Invalid username or password")

    form = AuthenticationForm()
    return render(request,
                  "main/login.html",
                  {"form":form})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve your goal without external libs by subclassing LoginForm from django.contrib.auth

Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54904773/django-adding-recaptcha-to-login-form) answer for code examples and a more detailed explanation. Using context processors you can also add the recaptcha public key into login.html template.

Answer (score 1):

You should post your `views.py`so I could help you better, but using common Django sense, you should render the `login.html` file with FormWithCaptcha as a context variable, named recaptcha, for example and then in your login file call it like {{recaptcha}} wherever you need it. But again, post your views file if your issue is not yet fixed.

```
def login_request(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AuthenticationForm(request, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                messages.info(request, f"You are now logged in as {username}")
                return redirect("main:homepage")
            else:
                messages.error(request, "Invalid username or password")

        else:
            messages.error(request, "Invalid username or password")

    form = AuthenticationForm()
    recaptcha = FormWithCaptcha()
    return render(request,
                  "main/login.html",
                  {"form":form, "recaptcha": recaptcha})
```

Comment: I added views.py!

Comment: I have the feeling you need to build your own custom AuthenticationForm (but because I don't know the library), you should add to your render the captcha form, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your help! I tried to add that piece to my code but i'm getting 'FormWithCaptcha' is not defined

Comment: Sorry friend, forgo the '()' -> recaptcha = FormWithCaptcha().

Comment: Yes! I imagined that's what you wanted to do! For some reason, though, i'm still getting the error. I'm reading into the repository to check where the error is

Comment: Ok, i think we need to use RecapthaField() instead of FormWithCaptcha() there. It's now working but i still can't see it into my login form. There should be an error in my html

Comment: Double check your urls.py file too.

Comment: Done, i got this on my webpage instead of the captcha form: <captcha.fields.ReCaptchaField object at 0x04B5C850>

Comment: Try this in your FormWithCaptcha. captcha = ReCaptchaField(widget= ReCaptchaV2Checkbox). The import for the widget is: from captcha.widgets import ReCaptchaV2Checkbox.

Comment: Not working. I tried with other libraries too, but none of them works. I don't know what i'm doing wrong yet

Comment: But if in your webpage it already shows <captcha.fields.ReCaptchaField object at 0x04B5C850> it means you're successfully passing an object to the frontend, you just need to figure it out how to render it. Try to follow this tutorial: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/02/21/how-to-add-recaptcha-to-django-site.html, in the comment section you have a small snippet to fix an issue when running in localhost (runserver) and to implement ajax logic.

Comment: Yeah i followed that tutorial too! The problem is that every time i will get 'invalid key' even if my key it's correct

Comment: There should be some problem with you configuration with Google API services

Comment: Yeah, trying to find where!