# Django - adding google recaptcha v2 to login form

Tags: python, django, recaptcha

I'm triying to add Recaptcha to my login form in Django. I tried different libraries but none of them seems to work, since the captcha form just doesn't appear in my template.

Here is my current work:

**urls.py**

```
path(r'captcha/', include('captcha.urls'))
```

**forms.py**

```
class NewUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class YourForm(forms.Form):
        captcha = CaptchaField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "email", "password1", "password2")

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(NewUserForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

And here is my **login.html** template

```
<form action="/your-name/" method="post">
   {% csrf_token %}
   {{ form.captcha }}
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

In this case, only the `Submit` button will appear, but not the `captcha` form. This is what happened with any other library I tried. Can anyone give me some help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: what if you move the captcha field outside of the nested class?

Comment: I tried, it won't even appear

Comment: If that's your real indentation, you made `captcha` a class attribute of the `YourForm` class which is itself a class attribute of the `NewUserForm` class, so you very obviously don't have a `captcha` field in the `NewUserForm`.  If you don't understand what all this means, then learning Python's basics might be a good idea... And if this is not you real indentation, then please edit your post with the REAL code

Answer (score 5):

It's difficult to directly help as you did not mention what library you were trying to use. Here is my approach to adding a v2 recaptcha to Django login, no additional libs required.

In this example, I add the recaptcha script to the django login template, and override django auth app's login view, in order to extend its functionality such that it validates the recaptcha server side (with the appropriate RECAPTCHA_SECRET as per [google docs](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify)).

Also note that context_processor is used to insert the RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY in the login template.

**login.html**

```
...
<head>
   <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer</script>
<script>
  function onSubmit(token) {
    document.getElementById("theForm").submit();
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="theForm">
<button class="g-recaptcha btn btn-primary" 
        data-callback="onSubmit" 
        data-sitekey="{{RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY}}" 
        type="submit">Login
</button>
</form>
</body>
...
```

**url.py**

```
...
# overriding auth app endpoint 
url(r'^accounts/login/', MyLoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
...
```

**context_processor.py**

```
from django.conf import settings 


def recaptcha_site_key(request):
    return {'RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY': settings.RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY}
```

**settings.py**

```
TEMPLATES = [
  {
    ...
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            ...
            'yourapp.context_processors.recaptcha_site_key',
            ...
        ],
    },
  },
]
```

**MyLoginView.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

def _validate_recaptcha(token, ip):
    # implement server side validation according to google docs
    pass    

class MyLoginView(auth_views.LoginView):
'''Edited per @avib answer
'''
    def post(self, form):

        request_body = self.request.POST
        if not request_body:
            return None
    
        recaptcha_token = request_body['g-recaptcha-response']
        ip_addr, _ = get_client_ip(self.request)
        if not _validate_recaptcha(recaptcha_token, ip_addr):
            # your logic
            return redirect('login')

    return super().post(form)
```

Answer (score 4):

@knopch1425 suggestion will invalidate the captcha token only on successful login.

[The LoginView form implementation](https://github.com/django/django/blob/202ac0b2a181f7be2e6c4a6ff43deef263d7f487/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L88) states that the `form_valid` method is only called after a successful login

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    """Security check complete. Log the user in."""
    auth_login(self.request, form.get_user())
    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

Instead you can override the `post` method in the following manner

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    request_body = self.request.POST
    if not request_body:
        return None

    recaptcha_token = request_body['g-recaptcha-response']
    ip_addr, _ = get_client_ip(self.request)
    if not _validate_recaptcha(recaptcha_token, ip_addr):
        # your logic
        return redirect('login')

    return super().post(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
```