# How to use form_validate() with CustomForm in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-views

I'm creating an app in which I'd like to use my own custom login form with a captcha field. My intention is to do this without using an external library (except for requests) but I couldn't add captcha field to my custom form in `forms.py`, so I added it directly to `login.html` but for some reason when I do `form.is_valid()` it returns an error.

I've already seen the solutions in [Django - adding google recaptcha v2 to login form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54904773/django-adding-google-recaptcha-v2-to-login-form) and [Adding a Recaptcha form to my Django login page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54884649/adding-a-recaptcha-form-to-my-django-login-page) but as I said, I'd like to do this without using an external library.

**views.py**

```py
...

def login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomLoginForm(request.POST)

        result = is_recaptcha_valid(request)
        print(result) # prints True

        if form.is_valid():

            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']

            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)

                # Redirect to index
                messages.success(request, "Logged in.")
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('orders:index'))
            else:
                messages.error(request, "Invalid credentials.")
        else:
            print("error")
            return render(request, 'registration/login.html', {'form': CustomLoginForm()})

    else:
            form = CustomLoginForm()
    return render(request, 'registration/login.html', {'form': form})
```

**forms.py**

```py
class CustomLoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(
        error_messages={
            'required': 'Please enter your email.',
            'invalid': 'Enter a valid email address.'
        },
        help_text='Email',
    )
```

**login.html**

```
  <form class="" action="{% url 'orders:login' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
      <p>
        {{ field.label_tag }}<br>
        {{ field }}
        {% if field.help_text %}
          <small style="color: grey">{{ field.help_text }}</small>
        {% endif %}
        {% for error in field.errors %}
          <p style="color: red">{{ error }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
      </p>
    {% endfor %}

    <!-- ReCAPTCHAV3 -->
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>

    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey='key-here'></div>
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="">Login</button>
    <!-- <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}"> -->
  </form>
```

`is_recaptcha_valid()` function already returns `True` so I didn't share that. I'm a beginner in Django, so if you can please explain in two words what I've done wrong instead of just posting the answer, I'd be grateful. Thank you for your time.

Comment: What is the problem here? What error are you getting?

Comment: I don't know the specific error, that's why I put that line `else print(error)` `if form.is_valid()` returns `False` in **views.py**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AuthenticationForm` is slightly different than the others..

If your check `AuthenticationForm` class, AuthenticationForm 's first arguments is not *data* like others form:

```
class AuthenticationForm(forms.Form):
    ...

    def __init__(self, request=None, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
```

Thats why you need to pass **request.POST** to *data*.

So update your code like this:

```
def login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomLoginForm(data=request.POST)
        ...
```

Comment: I did change the line to `print(form.errors)` but it prints out a blank line to the terminal.

Comment: To verify the problem, I've put a `print("Form ok.")` line right after the `if form.is_valid()` check but the program does not print that. So I suppose that the problem is with the form validation.

Comment: so the form is valid?. try to install ipdb and put `import ipdb;ipdb.set_trace()` before `form.is_valid()` statement, it will start debugging after you post your data check your terminal and press "n" key to continue every line and "c" key to pass.
please share your `AuthenticationForm`

Comment: I'm extending to the built-in [AuthenticationForm Class ] (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.AuthenticationForm) in Django, that's not a class I've written. IMHO the form is not valid as in the previous comment I've explained that.

Comment: ohhhh i know. try to change `form = CustomLoginForm(request.POST)` to `form = CustomLoginForm(data=request.POST)` :)

Comment: OMG it works! Thank you so much! But why? In the documentation for forms it doesn't say that I have to specify data argument. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/

Comment: if you can edit your answer so that I can mark this question as answered. I'd like to learn why this solution worked if you could explain it, thanks!

Comment: sry just got online again, i will update and write the explanation asap.